# passing variable beetween fragmentActivity and his fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am created a FragmentAcitivity and a ShareFragment. I want to pass variable (image url) from FragmentAcitivity to ShareFragment. I try to use bundle to get extras in ShareFragment  but it doesn't work. I put this in FragmentActivity

```
    private ShareFragment mShareFragment;
   FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mShareFragment = (ShareFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.sharefragment);
```

Sharefragment.java:

```
public class ShareFragment extends Fragment {
private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;
private OnShareContentChangedListener mShareContentChangedListener;
private ViewPager mViewPage;

// The resource to url mapping
private static final ArrayList<Pair<Integer, String>> IMAGE_IDS =
        new ArrayList<Pair<Integer, String>>() {{
            add(new Pair<>(R.drawable.goofy, "http://shareitexampleapp.parseapp.com/goofy/"));
            add(new Pair<>(R.drawable.liking, "http://shareitexampleapp.parseapp.com/liking/"));
            add(new Pair<>(R.drawable.viking, "http://shareitexampleapp.parseapp.com/viking/"));
        }};
private String _url;

@Override
public View onCreateView(
        LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    View view = inflater.inflate(share_it_view, container, false);

    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.connectWithFbButton);
    loginButton.setFragment(this);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile");

    setupViewPage(view);
    LikeView pageLike = (LikeView) view.findViewById(R.id.like_page);
    pageLike.setFragment(this);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    System.out.println(".......ONACTIVITYRESULT......."  );
}

public void setOnShareContentChangeListener(OnShareContentChangedListener listener) {
    mShareContentChangedListener = listener;


}

public String getCurrentShareContent() {

    return IMAGE_IDS.get(mViewPage.getCurrentItem()).second;
}

private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        ShareImageFragment imageFragment = new ShareImageFragment();
        imageFragment.setImage(IMAGE_IDS.get(position).first);
        return imageFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return IMAGE_IDS.size();
    }
}

private void setupViewPage(View view) {
    mViewPage = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    PagerAdapter adapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    mViewPage.setAdapter(adapter);

    final PageSelector pageSelector = (PageSelector) view.findViewById(R.id.page_selector);
    pageSelector.setImageCount(IMAGE_IDS.size());

    final LikeView photoLike = (LikeView) view.findViewById(R.id.like_photo);
    photoLike.setFragment(this);

    mViewPage.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(
                int position,
                float positionOffset,
                int positionOffsetPixels) {
            pageSelector.setPosition(position);
            String shareContent = IMAGE_IDS.get(position).second;
            photoLike.setObjectIdAndType(
                    shareContent,
                    LikeView.ObjectType.OPEN_GRAPH);
            mShareContentChangedListener.onShareContentChanged(shareContent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
}

public interface OnShareContentChangedListener {
    void onShareContentChanged(String content);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, Hope it helps

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
bundle.putString("name", name);
bundle.putString("address", address);
FragmentA fragmentA = new FragmentA();
fragmentA.setArguments(bundle);
```

then in fragment

```
String name = getArguments().getString("name"); 
String address = getArguments().getString("address");
```

Other way

Get the value in Fragment :

```
String name = ((C)getActivity()).getValue();

Toast.makeText(getActivity(), name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

C Class :

```
public String getValue()
{
   return trainerStrDescription;
}
```

Comment: Welcome!For getting answer to more queries follow coderzpassion.com